# Using SSL with the Flask CLI debug server?

Tags: ssl, flask, command-line-interface, google-oauth

I am creating a Flask app which uses Google OAuth to login user sessions which requires an SSL connection even for testing on my local system with a debug server.  I see I can setup a debug SSL certificate if I start my application using the `app.run(ssl_context=...)` method.  However, I do not see a way to setup SSL if I use the flask CLI start method:

```
FLASK_APP=MyApp FLASK_DEBUG=1 flask run
```

Is there a way to enable SSL on the above command line (which seems to be the current recommended method)?  I would prefer to continue to use this start method to make use of the automatic reloading feature which the CLI interface provides.

Or do I need to create a separate startup file with `app.run(...)` to enable SSL?  (And, I assume, loose the automatic reload feature)